# Draw a hexagonal prism using wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, 3d

To form a triangle prism I'm using

```
<GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
 <MeshGeometry3D 
                                    Positions="
                                      0,1,1  0,0,1  1,0,0  1,1,0
                                      1,1,0  0,1,0  0,1,1
                                      0,0,0  0,0,1  0,1,1  0,1,0
                                      0,0,0  0,1,0  1,1,0  1,0,0
                                      0,0,1  0,0,0  1,0,0

                                      "
                                    TriangleIndices="
                                       0,1,2     2,3,0 
                                       4,5,6
                                       7,8,9     7,9,10
                                       11,12,13  11,13,14 
                                       15,16,17
                                      " />
 </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
```

How should I change this code to make a hexagonal prism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that?

```
<GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
    <MeshGeometry3D
        Positions="
        0,0,0 1,0,0 2,1,0 1,2,0, 0,2,0, -1,1,0
        0,0,2 1,0,2 2,1,2 1,2,2, 0,2,2, -1,1,2
        "
        TriangleIndices="
        0,2,1 0,3,2 0,4,3 0,5,4
        6,7,8 6,8,9 6,9,10 6,10,11
        0,1,6 1,7,6
        1,2,7 2,8,7
        2,3,8 3,9,8
        3,4,9 4,10,9
        4,5,11 4,11,10
        5,0,6 5,6,11
        " />
</GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
```

Full sample:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollBar Name="vscroll" 
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
        Orientation="Vertical"  
        Minimum="-180" Maximum="180" 
        LargeChange="10" SmallChange="1" Value="0" />

    <ScrollBar Name="hscroll" 
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
        Orientation="Horizontal" 
        Minimum="-180" Maximum="180" 
        LargeChange="10" SmallChange="1" Value="0" />

    <Viewport3D Name="myViewport">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera FarPlaneDistance="10" LookDirection="-5,2,-3"
                                   UpDirection="0,1,0" NearPlaneDistance="0"
                                   Position="4.5,-1,4" FieldOfView="60">
                <PerspectiveCamera.Transform>
                    <Transform3DGroup>
                        <RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D
                                  Axis="0 1 0" 
                                  Angle="{Binding ElementName=hscroll, Path=Value}" />
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                        <RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D
                                  Axis="1 0 0" 
                                  Angle="{Binding ElementName=vscroll, Path=Value}" />
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                    </Transform3DGroup>
                </PerspectiveCamera.Transform>
            </PerspectiveCamera>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>

        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <AmbientLight Color="#0A0000A0" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="Red" Direction="0,0,-10" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="Green" Direction="-5,-8,3" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="Pink" Direction="12,4,-3" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="Pink" Direction="4,2,4" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>

                    <GeometryModel3D>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial>
                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray" Opacity="1.0" />
                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D
                                Positions="
                                0,0,0 1,0,0 2,1,0 1,2,0, 0,2,0, -1,1,0
                                0,0,2 1,0,2 2,1,2 1,2,2, 0,2,2, -1,1,2
                                "
                                TriangleIndices="
                                0,2,1 0,3,2 0,4,3 0,5,4
                                6,7,8 6,8,9 6,9,10 6,10,11
                                0,1,6 1,7,6
                                1,2,7 2,8,7
                                2,3,8 3,9,8
                                3,4,9 4,10,9
                                4,5,11 4,11,10
                                5,0,6 5,6,11
                                " />
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

The results:

[image: The results]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to add rotation using scrollbars?

Comment: @Dan For example, by applying `RotateTransform3D` to the camera, and than binding `Angle` property to the scroll value. See an update in the answer.